# how to make PageFlip in java

Tags: javascript, javafx, page-flipping

am developing a desktop application of reading **epub** files,am planning to do in **JavaFX** but my clients requirement is to give a pagination and pageflip (like [this](http://fliphtml5.com/examples/page-turn-book/index.html#p=7)) but in desktop application in java,dont know how to satisfy this requirement,please help me to do page flip in java

1.is there any libraries available for pageflip in java ?
2.can i use jquery in javafx to implement this ?
suggest me a good idea to solve this issue
thanks.

Comment: [jquery] is not a relevant tag - that's for JavaScript, not Java (they're quite different things).